# Why RxJs Record 2 events on long keypress?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to build a UI that responses to keyPress event.

> I am using **Angular** and **RxJS** to detect an event. *[Packages are uptodate]*

The code looks like

```
this.keyboard$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keypress')
     .pipe(debounceTime(300))
     .subscribe(e => {console.log(e);})
```

This code works fine in a normal scenario, but the edge case when the user presses a key for too long this records the second press event once the key is released.

There is a work around that I found, but keyup **defeats** the purpose.

```
this.keyboard$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
     .pipe(debounceTime(300))
     .subscribe(e => {console.log(e);})
```

**I need to detect one event per keypress.**

Can anyone please point out what is wrong with the snippet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about responding to keydown events?

Comment: @Michael Knight, it's the same as a keypress event :(

Comment: how about recording which key was pressed last and don't fire any further events until you have a keyup event with the matching key code?

Comment: User defines at what rate should `keypress` event be fired when a key is down. You can't pick the right debounce time for that. What you could try is to play with mixing `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup` event streams, but that is troublesome and highly depends on your particular needs. If you could describe your use case — we could be of better help

Comment: @kos, Use case: I need to detect one event per keypress or key down. And as soon as the key is hit a need to call a function.

Comment: They why not use my solution. Have a variable which holds the key code of the most recently pressed key and another variable which will determine if the event will cause your function to be called. Each time a key is pressed call you function then don't allow your function to be called again until you hear a keyup event with the right code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually its not a bug.
When you hold a key, the browser resend the same event. Its Called Key Repeat.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

To avoid the Key Repeat, you could filter repeated events using the 'repeat' property.

```
const { fromEvent} = rxjs;
const {filter, map} = rxjs.operators;

var keyboard$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
  .pipe(filter(event => !event.repeat))
  .subscribe(event => {
    console.log(event.code);

  })
```

Ive created a JSFiddle here so you can try it by yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/williamxsp/Lq9go1bt/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Angular but I think it would look something like this:

have a variable which holds the key code of the most recently pressed key and another variable which will determine if the event will cause your function to be called. Each time a key is pressed call you function then don't allow your function to be called again until you hear a keyup event with the right code

```
var KeyUpHasOccurred = true;
var KeyCode;

this.keyboard$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
 .pipe(debounceTime(300))
 .subscribe(e => {
     if(KeyUpHasOccurred)
         console.log(e);
         KeyUpHasOccurred = false;
         KeyCode = e.key
 })

this.keyboard$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
 .pipe(debounceTime(300))
 .subscribe(e => {
      if(e.key = KeyCode)
          KeyUpHasOccurred = true;
  })
```

Comment: 1. I can press several keys at once and release them in any order I want, not sure how that will be handled

Comment: 2. the `debounceTime` will ignore a lot of events if typed rapidly

Comment: You could change the KeyUpHasOccurred into an array and store a boolean for each keyCode instead if you wanted it so that you could continue to respond to other keydown events from other keys.

Comment: I got the idea of this workaround when combined with array thought, this should work well but. I still don't understand the point of RxJS sending two events

Comment: As I say I'm not familiar with Angular or the RxJS API and I only use jsx in React. I wouldn't say it's sending two event but instead listening to two observables i.e. keydown and keyup and you need to listen/observe both of these events in your particular case.